# How do I properly format a CSS navigation bar so that it is at the top center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am new to building websites so if I am going about this the wrong way, please let me know. My code is below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
<header>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>

</body>
<footer>

</footer>
```

CSS: I attempted to place a "text-align: center;" in the li, ul, and a elements, but that did not work. I may be getting the wrong idea of how to properly format a navigation bar.

```
header 
{
    text-align: center;
}
header nav ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: right;
}

header nav ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav ul li a:hover 
{
    background-color: #6600CC;
}

body 
{
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

Comment: Use margin: 0 auto;.  But also make sure that you div holding the content you want centered is 100%, so it takes up the entire allowable space.

Comment: Welcome to SO - great that you've added code to show but please, make your question a bit clearer... what are you trying to do? What's the expected output?

Comment: My apologies that I was not clear enough in my question Darren. By looking at durbnpoisn's comment I believe I have figured out where I would like to go with this now. Basically I am still in the stage of figuring out best practices on laying out web pages. The navigation bar is the first thing I am trying to tackle. I was attempting to create a navigation bar that is centered towards the top of the page and spans across the entire page. Right now the nav bar does not expand completely across the page.